# Beginnings of a Scattergories program

Tags: c++, beginner, game, random

I wrote this program as a start towards implementing the game *Scattergories*.  I had a problem with the `_sleep` command so I used `Sleep` in the `windows.h` library.

Eventually, I would like to add a way to either check if a word is correct, or to suggest words, and to activate a sound when the timer is done.

```
// A program to keep track of points and time and to give a random letter for the game scattergories

#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

void ltr()    //gives a random letter
{
    char letter;
    letter = rand() % 27 + 64;         //assigns a random letter in ascii code to a char (resulting in a random letter)
    cout << "The letter is " << letter << "\n";
}

void clock()   //timer
{
    cout << "You got 1.5 minutes to finish\n";
    for (int i = 90; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << i << "\n";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    cout << "DING DONG!!! DING DONG!!! Time's up!!!\n";
}

int points()        //points per round
{
    int a, b, c, sum;
    cout << "How many sections only you got?\n";          //worth 15 points
    cin >> a;
    cout << "How many words only you got?\n";       //worth 10 points
    cin >> b;
    cout << "How many words you and another person got?\n";    //worth 5 points
    cin >> c;
    sum = a * 15 + b * 10 + c * 5;
    return sum;           //Note: It doesn't matter how many sections there are.
}

int act()
{
    int Points;
    ltr();
    clock();
    Points=points();
    cout << "You have earned " << Points << " this round\n\n";
    return Points;
}

int main()
{
    int Points;
    cout << "Starting in five seconds\n";
    Sleep(5000);
    Points = act();
    for (;;)          //inf loop
    {
        int ph;
        cout << "Press 1 to continue or 2 to stop\n";
        cin >> ph;
        if (ph == 1)
        {
            Points += act();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "You have earned a total of " << Points << " great job!\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use c++11 features? If so, I'd see a number of things to improve.

Comment: Please don't change the question after receiving input. Editing the code invalidates  the answers.

Comment: I've already rolled it back. But you can do it yourself anytime too. Now it's no longer necessary, but maybe next time.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Feel free to write a follow-up question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use portable code as much as possible

You should avoid

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

when you can use portable c++ features (according the current c++ standard) instead:

```
Sleep(1000);
```

should be

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); // needs to #include <thread>
```

As you see that's much more readable, and will compile on other operating system environments as well.

### Use a better random number generator

```
letter = rand() % 27 + 64;
```

Doesn't provide a good random number generator (besides you missed to initialize the seed with `srand()` and your program will produce the same sequence of random numbers with every run).

C++ provides easy to use and configurable (regarding the wanted number distribution requirements) random generators like listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberDistribution).

### Do not use `system("pause");`

Besides that statement isn't portable again, it introduces security problems. If there's a program existent and accessible at the system called `pause` that doesn't do what's intended (but some malicious things instead), that one will be executed.

If you wan't to wait for some input rather use `std::cin >> dummy;` or such.

### Check the state of input operations

```
 cin >> ph;
```

You never checked that the user inputted a valid number. If something like `xxxx` is entered, your loop will never stop.

Better do something like:

```
bool stop = false;
do
{
    int ph;
    cout << "Press 1 to continue or 2 to stop\n";
    if(cin >> ph) {
         if (ph == 1)
         {
             Points += act();
         }
         else if(ph == 2)
         {
             stop = true;
         }
    }
    else {
         cin.clear();
         std::string dummy;
         std::getline(cin,dummy); // Consume the invalid input
    }
} while(!stop);
```

---

> I would like to add a way to either check if a word is correct, or to suggest words but it would mean I need to connect it to a dictionary of some sort (which I don't know how to do).

You can use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to create dictionaries.

I can't give you any sample code how to integrate these in your program, since it's unclear for me how you wan't to make use of these exactly.

Comment: @L.F. Of course it was. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

After taking the input I added `srand()` with the `time.h` header to prevent getting the same pattern of letters every time starting the program.
I also removed the `windows.h` header and used `_sleep` (which now works, still have no idea why) and removed the `system("pause")`.
Also a possible way to add a table

The new code:

```
/* To do list:
   *Convert to arduino
   *Make timer work in background of of table
   *Check if words in the table (for differant players) are the same and give points accordingly
   *Check if words are actual words (connect an online dictonary?)
   *Make interface? (if possible and I have time to learn how)
   *Think of what to do with Hardwear
   *Comment rest of the code
*/


// A program to keep track of points and time and to give a random letter for the game scattergories
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<string>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::getline;

void ltr()    //gives a random letter
{
    srand(time(NULL));    //gives a differant pattern every time
    char letter;
    letter = rand() % 27 + 64;         //assigns a random letter in ascii code to a char (resulting in a random letter)
    cout << "The letter is " << letter << "\n";
}

void timer()
{
    cout << "You got 1.5 minutes to finish\n";
    for (int i = 90; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << i << "\n";
        _sleep(1000);
    }
    cout << "DING DONG!!! DING DONG!!! Time's up!!!\n";
}

void table()
{
    int plr, ctr;
    string lst[5][20];           //first dimantion: how many players. second dimantion: how many catagories, third dimantion(if added) will be the round
    cin>>plr>>ctr;       //parameters for later
    cin.ignore();                  //To avoid the "getline" reading the last input
    for(int x=0;x<plr;x++)       //the player changes only after the previus player finishes
    {
        timer();
        for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)        //changing catagory
        {
            getline(cin,lst[x][i]);
        }
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Next player\n";
    }
    for(int x=0;x<plr;x++)                   //this part (the whole "for" loop) is for confirming
    {
        cout<<"Player number "<<x+1<<": ";
        for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
        {
            cout<<lst[x][i]<<"    ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    _sleep(5000);
}

int points()        //points per round
{
    int a, b, c, sum;
    cout << "How many sections only you got?\n";          //worth 15 points
    cin >> a;
    cout << "How many words only you got?\n";       //worth 10 points
    cin >> b;
    cout << "How many words you and another person got?\n";    //worth 5 points
    cin >> c;
    sum = a * 15 + b * 10 + c * 5;
    return sum;           //Note: It doesn't matter how many sections there are.
}

int act()
{
    int Points;
    ltr();
    table();
    Points = points();
    cout << "You have earned " << Points << " this round\n\n";
    return Points;
}

int main()
{
    int Points;
    cout << "Starting in five seconds\n";
    _sleep(5000);
    Points = act();
    for (;;)          //inf loop
    {
        int ph;
        cout << "Press 1 to continue or anything else to stop\n";
        cin >> ph;
        if (ph == 1)
        {
            Points += act();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "You have earned a total of " << Points << " great job!";
    _sleep(5000);       //time to read the last text
    return 0;
}
```